# How to use strel('disk')

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to make a disk of 1's in my matrix of all zeros. I need the origin of this disk to be at a particular point. This is in MATLAB.

I have tried making a disk but I do not know how to apply `se` to my image Img.

```matlab
Img = zeros(15,15);
Img(8,8) = 1;

se = strel('disk', 6);
```

I want a 15x15 matrix with a disk of radius 6 of 1s on the origin (8, 8), and 0s everywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structuring element `se` is applied to the image using [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html):

```matlab
Img = zeros(15,15);
Img(8,8) = 1;

se = strel('disk', 6);

Img = imdilate(Img,se);
```

Dilating an image with a single set pixel yields an image with the structuring element centered at that pixel.